# Check if a column exists in Joomla table

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I've a table with the columns `id` and `name`. I want to know if another new column `filters` exist (of course it doesn't exist). 
This is what I'm doing

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `#__facets` LIKE 'filters'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$res = $db->query();
```

If I print `$res` it shows `resource(675) of type (mysql result)` when I was expecting `NULL` because column doesnt exist.

If I try with `name` (the column exist):

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `#__facets` LIKE 'name'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$res= $db->query();
```

It returns also `resource(234) of type (mysql result)`.

How can I control if the column exist? The query is OK because it works on MySQL Workbench
PS: I'm using Joomla 1.5 so I can't use `getTableColumns()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the `$res= $db->query();` line.

To get the desired `NULL` I had to `loadResult()` instead of just `query()`. So the correct code is:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `#__facets` LIKE 'filters'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$res = $db->loadResult();
```